# Range-based for loops in C++11 segfault, but not with regular for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, segmentation-fault, auto

```
//fills my vector with pointers.
//(some are pointing places, others are set to nullptr  
vector<Tree_NodeT*> xml_trees {Build_Tree_List(program_options->Get_Files())};

//time to print them
for (auto tree = xml_trees.begin(); tree != xml_trees.end(); ++tree){
    if (*tree){
        (*tree)->Print(std::cout,4);
    }
}
//this worked! No Segfaults!

//time to print them again
for (auto tree : xml_trees){
    if (tree){
        tree->Print(std::cout,4);
    }
}
//Crash! Segfault.
```

Why is the second loop segfaulting, while the first loop is not?

Comment: Pointer dereference? No idea, just thinking out of my ass

Comment: To clarify, no experience with C++11 yet, but why don't you dereference in the second loop? - I'm assuming C++ auto dereferences for you?

Comment: @AK4749, `tree` in the second loop is each `Tree_NodeT*` in the vector, where in the first loop, it's more like a pointer to the `Tree_NodeT*`.

Comment: @AK4749 because tree is an iterator.  I have to dereference the iterator to get to my pointer, and then I have to use '->' to dereference my pointer and call a Tree_NodeT's method

Comment: Man, now i feel stupid, should have known that without C++11 haha thanks! coffee time...

Comment: Step through the loop line by line in a debugger, so you can see what really happens. It _should_ work as far as I can see, but stepping in a debugger is never a bad idea.

Comment: Does the `Print` function somehow mutate the container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**
I am a liar.
Tree_NodeT pointers were being created, but **not** initialized to nullptr somewhere in the Build_Tree_List function.  Thus, I got a vector back where some of the pointers were pointing to valid memory, and others were just newly constructed pointers not set to null or given any address.  It is still interesting that the first loop was able to handle this without crashing, while the second one segfaulted.

Comment: That is the nature of undefined behavior, it's undefined so anything could happen, even [demons flying out of you nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: I prefer the undefined behavior of a nuclear missile attack on the surface of Mars.

Answer (score 3):

Your range for loop is equivalent to:

```
for (auto it = xml_trees.begin(); it != xml_trees.end(); ++it) {
    auto tree = *it;
    if (tree){
        (tree)->Print(std::cout,4);
    }
}
```

The difference is that the range for loop is copy-constructing the dereferenced iterator.  To get similar behaviour to your traditional for loop, use `auto &`:

```
for (auto &tree: xml_trees){
    if (tree){
        tree->Print(std::cout,4);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it, the dereferenced iterator is just a `Tree_NodeT*`, so copy-constructing (copying) it shouldn't cause any trouble.

Comment: @Prætorian hmm, yeah.  Guess it could also be the repeated calling of `end()` as opposed to just calling it at the start.